# Timeout on pax exam (karaf) unit-test on linux jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, cxf, apache-karaf, pax-exam

I have started using PAX-EXAM with Karaf container to test our application.
Sometimes the test just hangs before the test methods starts and it always hangs on cxf registering mbeans:

registering MBean org.apache.cxf:bus.id=service-cxf1915658948,type=Bus.Service.Endpoint,service="{http://org.service/}Service",port="Service",instance.id=888648364: javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean@2dc85fc

Anyone knows why this occurs?

Pax-exam: 3.4.0
Karaf-container: 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

You should use the latest Karaf Container 2.3.3, afairc with 2.3.2 onward the blueprint graceperiod issue had been fixed or better worked around, this might lead to these situations.

Comment: Will try this, good though is that I'm now using pax, very easy to try 2.3.3 with my application.